# Flutter setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

My app by default opens `welcome` screen and in that screen I've placed code to check whether user is logged or not. If logged redirect to home otherwise stay in welcome screen but now it returns this error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

`welcome.dart`

```
  late Box userBox;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userBox = Hive.box<Usermodel>('user'); // get user box

    // see if user data exist in storage or not?
    if(userBox.values.isNotEmpty && userBox.get(0).name.toString().isNotEmpty) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home'); // if exist redirect to home screen
    }
  }
```

**any idea how to solve this error?**

## Update

If my user is already logged `Vinoth Vino` answer works fine, but if my user is not logged in it throw this error:

```
Null check operator used on a null value
```

Which comes from  `userBox.get(0)!.name`

If I remove `!` after my `get(0)` then it says

```
The getter 'name' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: name
```

## Update 2

Apparently my user data did not store in my box (which is strange because it did store in first time) so it's returning `null`, but there is 2 issues involve with this being `null`

1. I do save my user data after the success login so it should be there.

```
//store data in storage in login screen 
var userData = Usermodel()
..name = user.name
..email = user.email
..createdAt = user.createdAt
..approved = user.approved;
final box = Hive.box<Usermodel>('user');
await box.add(userData);
```

2. even let say it did not store user data in box then why am I redirecting to home screen? ( I am checking for nullity right? `userBox.values.isNotEmpty && userBox.get(0).name.toString().isNotEmpty` it shouldn't redirect)

Comment: Maybe you've null with `Hive.box<Usermodel>('user')`. Try this one `userBox.get(0)?.name ?? 'Not Found'`

Comment: Can you check `userBox` is null? If not, then check the userBox's `name` is null or not?

Comment: @VinothVino Apparently it's null but there is 2 issues involve with this being null `1` I do save my user data after the success login so it should be there `2` even let say it did not store user data in box then why am I redirecting to home screen?

Comment: Yup, you need to navigate it to login screen if the hive returns null. It's better to create userBox as nullable property and then check if it is null or not. If null, open login screen or else home screen

Comment: Can you check my updated answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the condition inside the [addPostFrameCallback()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), this callback will trigger once the build method completes.

```
Box? userBox;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  userBox = Hive.box<Usermodel>('user'); // get user box

  if (userBox != null) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if(userBox.values.isNotEmpty && userBox.get(0).name.toString().isNotEmpty) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home'); // if exist redirect to home screen
      }
    });

    or

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if(userBox.values.isNotEmpty && userBox.get(0).name.toString().isNotEmpty) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home'); // if exist redirect to home screen
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Navigate to login screen
  }
}
```

**Update**

Yup, you need to navigate it to login screen if the hive returns null. It's better to create `userBox` as `nullable property` and then check if it is null or not. If null, open login screen or else home screen

Comment: Hi, the error is back :/ this time says `Null check operator used on a null value` here is the logic: `1` if my user is logged in your code works just fine `2` if my user still hasn't logged in it throw this error. `code`: `userBox.get(0)!.name`

Comment: Can you update your question with stacktrace? Maybe you've null with `Hive.box<Usermodel>('user')`

Comment: how do I can userBox null?

Comment: Check this one https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety and https://dart.dev/null-safety for null safety

Comment: **Question:** let say I logged once and logged out `userBox.delete(0);` then I logged again could it be this time my user not be `0`  `get(0)`? maybe that's the issue? my current user for instance now is `get(10)`?

Comment: Yup, that's the issue I guess? Just check each line with breakpoint and inspect the variables whether it's null or not then you'll get an idea to fix that.

Comment: My apologies but it's my first attempt on hive how can I check that? and most importantly: is there a way that I set specific key for my user row so I always can have only 1 row instead of many rows and need to filter them out? let say I hard code `0` then regardless how many times user login/logout it always re-write this `0` row.

Comment: **Found the solution :D** instead of hard coding `0` in get I now use `userBox!.keys.last` so it always return key of latest row `${userBox.get(userBox.keys.last).name}`